# Basic questions about ontology manipulation

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

My questions are probably very basic, but they are fundamental for me since they put all puzzles together.

1) As I understand, ontologies (*.owl) might be either "empty" (without data, i,e, without individuals) or they may involve both the relations between classes and linked data. Is it correct?

2) I downloaded a famous `gene_ontology.owl`, which seems to contain both data and meta-structure. How can I start creating SPARQL queries? The queries always specify endpoints, classes names, etc. e.g. `PREFIX  dcore:  <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>`. Where do I get all these titles for particular ontology? Should I try to figure out all the titles using e.g. Protégé or is there any "automatic" way to create queries?

Comment: For 1, look up "TBox" and "ABox".  OWL ontologies are sets of axioms.  Some axioms a "terminological" (declare classes and properties and the relations between them), and some as assertional (declare individuals and their properties and types), though the distinction isn't complete.  Some ontologies might be primarily terminological, which is what it sounds like you're asking.

Comment: For 2, you'd need to store the RDF mapping of the OWL ontology (there's a good chance that it's already stored as RDF) into a triple store and then execute queries against the triple store.  There are no special prefix names that you have to use, though there might be some usual conventions.  You might find some common ones online, but in general, you'll need to have some idea of what's *in* the ontology, and that means reading the documentation about the ontology, or inspecting it by hand.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: Thanks. Can I store the RDF mapping of the OWL ontology using Protégé? Something like Export As... or Save As..

Comment: Yes. As I recall, when you "Save As" in Protege, some of the options are RDF-based (RDF/XML, Turtle or N3, etc.).